# Wrong NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED and SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE Error

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

Here's what I did:

1. I setup nginx with my ssl certificate/key, and everything worked well. I got the secured connection I wanted.
2. During some other installation process, I had to get back to plain http without the certificates.
3. I switched back to ssl again.

Now what is happening is; if I use a fresh new PC (or even a new browser) I can get into the website without any problems, the certificate is valid and recognized on all browsers.

However, on my workstation, I cannot, I guess because I entered it from Chrome previously (after step 1). Installed Firefox, and I am not getting the error as well. Repeated the steps 2 and 3 and Firefox stated to give the very same error.

All SSL certificate checkers show a valid SSL status of the website.

I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Is your server sending any HPKP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning) headers?  And you've checked it with ssllabs.com?

Comment: @JasonMartin I have just checked. Yes and yes. It looks like it is sending a SHA 256 pin.

Comment: Is it the correct pin for your server? That could account for first-view-works followed by an error.

Comment: It is correct, I am afraid.

Comment: Can you say what the url is? It is hard to discern further without that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't make a comment since this is a new account. But if you are using an StartCom SSL this may be the problem:

Mozilla and Google decided to distrust all StartCom root certificates as of 21st of October, this situation will have an impact in the upcoming release of Firefox and Chrome in January. Apple's decision announced on Nov 30th of distrusting all StartCom root certificates as of 1st of December will have an impact in their upcoming security update.

StartCom will provide an interim solution soon and will replace all the issued certificates with issuance date on or after Oct 21st in case of requested. Meanwhile StartCom is updating all systems and will generate new root CAs as requested by Mozilla to regain the trust in these browsers.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using StartCom SSL. And even if I did, Mozilla and Chrome can still validate on other computers. So I think it is not related.